# Unable to boot to BIOS screen (Uefi blank black screen)

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, uefi, cmos

I have recently been unable to access my uefi bios i think it is since upgrading to windows 10 but im not sure

I used to be able to access the bios fine but it was a while since i have changed my boot order etc and i needed to change it recently and couldn't

Everything else works fine, I can access some sort of boot menu using f8 which i have used as a work around
but I really need to access the uefi.
Is there anyway to rollback bios firmware or to re-install firmware without being able to access the BIOS?

What happens is turn on the computer press f2 or del for bios and then i get a black screen that just hangs until i restart but windows starts fine

I have also tried re-setting the bios with the CMOS battery, and also trying different video leads and connections.

specs are:
asus p8z77-v
i5 3570k
8gb corsair ram
gtx 1070
120gb ssd 
2 1 tb hard drives
windows 10 64 bit

Comment: You can update or rewrite the BIOS from Windows. Go here and download the BIOS update and the program required for the update: https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/P8Z77V/HelpDesk_Download/

Comment: Ok thanks, is the tool asus winflash? i cant find any software on that page you linked I think they used to have some software called AI Suite but its not on the page anymore.

Comment: Yes. That one is about flashing the BIOS.

Comment: I have same problem on Asus X552CL laptop, reflashing bios from version 201 to latest 207 with winflash has no effect.